# stop a session from timeouting on PHP

Tags: php, session, timeout

I'm making a project on PHP and it pretty much doesn't involve any human intervention, in other words, I'm making a special script that should run for a long time (a user visits my website and the script keeps running until the user exits...). The one problem that is concerning me is:

Won't the sessions expire when the script runs like this for a while? If So how could I bypass that, so it could run for a very a long time?

Oh, And one more question: Could my PHP script start by its own without any user intervention? If so, How could I configure it to do so?

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/678801) will probably be relevant to you.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish it's pretty much impossible to answer your question.  I will say this though, PHP isn't really made for long-running scripts.  It's made for short-lived request/response cycles.  If you need something to keep running on the server you might be better off looking at java, node.js, or any of a number of other languages that are better suited to the task.

Comment: Also, is timeouting a real word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run PHP from the command line. Those scripts do not have a timeout like user-called scripts. Otherwise, you can set the timeout with set_time_limit like

```
 set_time_limit(0); // 0 means no limit
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to avoid the timeout.
2. For the PHP script to start on its own, you could use a [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)